# viewport resize event for flash player

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to all of this and can't figure out how to resize the flash player I use for my home media server when the window is resized or orientation changes. I am basing the player size on the size of the viewport. I have searched and tried various versions but they don't work which is most likely due to my lack of knowledge.
Most of the code below was already done, I have commented what I added here for reference.

[**Link to a sample**](http://173.27.137.207:52190/Gizmo/play_flash.html?File=526828)

**viewport.js** (added by me)

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

**html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Gizmo play_flash</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/viewport.js"></script>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=noscript.html"></noscript>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #000000">
<div id="outer">

    <div class="player_wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0px auto;">
        <div id="player">
            Loading the video player ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('player').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'scripts/player.swf',
            'file': '[File.FlashLink]',
            'autostart': 'true',
            'duration': '[File.Duration]',
            'provider': 'scripts/jrmediaprovider.swf',
            'skin': 'scripts/glow.zip',
                    <!--begin mod-->
            'width': width - 5,
            'height': height - 5
                    <!--endmod-->
        });

        jwplayer('player').onComplete(
            function(event) { 
                try {
                    window.Gizmo.onComplete();
                } catch (err) { }
            }
        );
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've spent days now looking for a solution to this issue. Unfortunately there is no way do this consistantly on mobile, see: http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html

Answer (score 20):

Just bind to the `window` object on the `resize` and `orientationChange` events and use the `JW Player` `resize` method after getting the new width and height.

Something like this.

```
$(window).on('resize orientationChange', function(event) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    jwplayer('player').resize(width, height);
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Like I said I am a complete NuB to this. I am not even sure where it would go. (js or html)

Answer (score 3):

Using the DOM API to detect viewport resize:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (ev) => {
  console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});
```